# Converting RDD[Array[Double]] to DataFrame[Array[Double]] produces DataFrame[WrappedArray]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have an RDD with the form `long, int, string, Array[Double]` which I need to convert to a DataFrame. The conversion of `myRDD.toDF()` works fine but my problem is that the Array[Double] feature is converted to a WrappedArray[Double]. The resulting schema is:

```
root
 |-- _1: long (nullable = false)
 |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- _3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

The issue I am having is that I cannot apply operations on the `_4` column as if it were an array of values which I can do on the RDD. The `WrappedArray`columns seems to be treated as a string starting with `WrappedArray(10.0, 33.4, 1.2, ...)`. On the RDD I can apply maps on these elements but not on the DataFrame column. What is the correct way to convert an `Array[Double]` element from an RDD to a DataFrame column so that the values are treated as a series of numbers, not a string `"WrappedArray(....)"`

Comment: what operation do you want to do on _4 column. there are so many inbuilt functions you can apply and moreover you can use udf functions to apply you custom logics . Just specify the operation you want to perform

Comment: I am trying to sample 5 rows, transpose, and create a new array with average values over those 5 row. This is not working  because the "Array" is getting treated as a string. I am going to try parsing the text (dropping the "WrappedArray(" and splitting on the commons), but this seems very inefficient.

Comment: can you update the question with sample input and expected output

Comment: "The `WrappedArray` columns seems to be treated as a string …"  That doesn't happen spontaneously.  You're almost certainly doing something you did not intend to do involving an unexpected conversion to `String`.